# Combination of groupby and mean methods

Tags: statistics, dataframe, groupby, methods, mean

I am looking at the below csv file :

[image]

We have the question :

Display the mean of the variable gre by group of admitted/not admitted students, using the combination of groupby and mean methods.

I would write :

```
df['gre'].mean(df.groupby('admit'))
```

But the correct answer is :

```
df[['gre', 'admit']].groupby('admit').mean()
```

Why do we write before we call the groupby method both columns gre and admit ?

Answer (score 0):

By writing both columns before calling the `groupby` method, you are telling the `groupby` function to group the data by the `admit` column and then perform the mean calculation on the `gre` column. This will provide the mean of the `gre` column grouped by the `admit` column.

Comment: So do we always write df[[col1, col2, col3]].method1().method2().method3() and the method1 is applied at col3, method2 at col2 and mathod3 at col1 ? But why do we write 'admit' again when we call the groupby method?